# Export data table from Databricks dbfs to azure sql database

Tags: sql, azure, pyspark, databricks

I am quite new to databricks and looking for a smart way to export a data table from databricks gold scheme to an azure sql database.
I am using databricks as a part of azure resource group, however I do not find data from databricks in any of the storage accounts that are within the same resource group. Does it mean that is is physically stored at en implicit databricks storage account/data lake?
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

The tables you see in Databricks could be have the data stored within that Databricks Workspace file system (DBFS) or somewhere external (e.g. Data Lake, which could be in a different Azure Resource Group) - see here: [Databricks databases and tables](https://docs.databricks.com/data/tables.html)

For writing data from Databricks to Azure SQL, I would suggest the [Apache Spark connector for SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15).